# My blade does not show the style inside a model view

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade

I am using some styles in my laravel project, but the style does not work inside a model view, but it works if I redirect it to another direcction.

THIS DOES NOT WORK:

php artisan route:list:

```
Route::resource('/films', 'FilmsController');
```

This is the controller:

```
public function show(Film $film)
{

    return view('films.show', compact('film'));
}
```

Nevertheless this yes:

```
Route::get('/show', function () {
    return view('films.show');
});
```

HERE I LOAD THE CSS:

```
<title>SB Admin 2 - Dashboard</title>

<!-- Custom styles for this template-->
<link href="css/admin-app.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/vendor.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/nirea.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

THIS IS PART OF MY ROUTE:LIST

[Image of the web.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyHeB.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "it works if I redirect it to another direction"?

Comment: Please show the view code where you load the css files

Comment: I mean that it loads the css. The funny thing is that I am loading it in a layout and then I am extending it. It loads sometimes and other times no.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something in your `films.show` blade file is causing the issue.

You said that manually pointing a route to the view works while using the controller doesn't.

Are you using `/films/{id}` in your url? The resource controller is expecting a resource id in the url in order to "show" that specific resource. Your manual test does not refer to a specific Film to display results about.

Perhaps look over the resource documentation one more time to see how resource controllers work. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers

In essence,

```
| Verb      | URI                | Action  | Route Name    |
|-----------|--------------------|---------|---------------|
| GET       | /films             | index   | films.index   |
| GET       | /films/create      | create  | films.create  |
| POST      | /films             | store   | films.store   |
| GET       | /films/{film}      | show    | films.show    |
| GET       | /films/{film}/edit | edit    | films.edit    |
| PUT/PATCH | /films/{film}      | update  | films.update  |
| DELETE    | /films/{film}      | destroy | films.destroy |
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. If I am not wrong I have those like you.

I am going to post it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the css. It was not loading the css.

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('/css/admin-app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ URL::asset('/css/vendor.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ URL::asset('/css/nirea.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Thanks everybody for answering.